# Difference between periods in crosstabs, Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I'm working with Jaspersoft Studio.
I've a crosstab similar to this one:

```
+---------+------+------+
| FRUIT   | 2014 | 2015 |
+---------+------+------+
| apples  |  12  |  85  |
+---------+------+------+
| peaches |  74  |  36  |
+---------+------+------+
| bananas |  54  |  82  |
+---------+------+------+
```

and I would like to obtain something like this:

```
+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| FRUIT   | 2014 | 2015 |      Difference     |
|         |      |      |   between 2015/2014 |
|         |      |      |       (delta)       |
+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| apples  |  12  |  85  |          73         |
+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| peaches |  74  |  36  |         -38         |
+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| bananas |  54  |  82  |          28         |
+---------+------+------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible?
I mean, it's there a way to intercetpt the value of a field in the single period (e.g. 2014) and use it for a custom calculation?

Comment: Yes, you can use variables

Comment: What result do you expect for 3 or more years?

Comment: My query selects only two periods. I would like to perform delta between the two periods. I've tried with variables but, because of the values are the result of a count, the variable just returns the number 1.

Comment: You should post the report's template

Comment: @AlexK I've post my Jrxml file

Comment: I think it will be better to use the Table component in your case. `My query selects only two periods` - If you always get only two years, it is not a truly crosstab.